# Can we make Slave Server as Master for another Slave server?

Tags: mysql

Currently we have Master-Slave Setup in two servers, now can we make Slave server as Master to another Slave server?

Final setup should be like this..

Master=====> Slave/Master =====> Slave

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Yes, you just need to make sure you configure `log-slave-updates`. Is there a reason you want to chain rather than have multiple read slaves from the same master?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andy... I Just want know..